# javascript convert int to float

Tags: javascript

I have a variable

```
var fval = 4;
```

now I want out put as 4.00

Answer (score 153):

JavaScript only has a *Number* type that stores floating point values.

There is no int.

**Edit:**

If you want to format the number as a string with two digits after the decimal point use:

```
(4).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: in php we have function number_format which adds floating points like that do we have any function in javascript

Comment: While this does what the question asked for, be careful using toFixed. toFixed returns a string, so if you try to add another number to it, it treats it as a string concatenation, not a number addition.

Comment: @AaronGloege Is there a way to keep it as a "number"?

Comment: @dollarvar No there isn't. The *number* type uses a binary floating point representation intended for calculation. It can't distinguish between 4 and 4.00. In fact it can't represent all decimal numbers accurately, but that's a whole nother story.

Comment: Thanks, I found out though, that calculations with, eehm now I am confused how to call it, numbers with a point are unexactly, so there is no use too keep it as an "integer". ;)

Comment: Use `parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);` and to keep it number permanently `parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon Thanks!
Yours should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

**toFixed()** method formats a number using fixed-point notation. Read [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for full reference.

```
var fval = 4;

console.log(fval.toFixed(2)); // prints 4.00
```

Comment: YRW. And dont forget to clean up no longer required comments ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
var fval = 4;
var fvalfloat = parseFloat(fval).fixed(2)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.