# How do I add a decimal notation to a number without devision?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I get from var x:number = 1200 to x = 1.200 or var x: number = 8 to x = 8.0 ?

Comment: Can you explain why 1200 becomes 1.200 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript convert int to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057489/javascript-convert-int-to-float)

Comment: Is that dot a grouping char, or a decimal?

Comment: Possibly you want [How to format numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Method [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will help you.

```
x = 1200
x = x.toFixed(1) // 1200.0
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, don't know what you want :

```
const conv = (num) => {
  arr = [...('' + num)] ;
  arr.splice(1, 0, '.')
  if (arr[arr.length-1] == '.') arr.push('0') ;
  return arr.join('')
}
console.log( conv(1200), conv(8) ) // 1.200 8.0
```